# Compile error: ` fatal error: gfc_todo: `

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

When I compile my code with

```
     gfortran -O2 calpuff.for -o calpuff.exe
```

The following code:

```
      REAL FUNCTION R1MACH (I)
C***BEGIN PROLOGUE  R1MACH
C   ...
      real SMALL(2)
      real LARGE(2)
      real RIGHT(2)
      real DIVER(2)
      real LOG10(2)
c --- Set up for IBM PC: declare as reals   ..........(DGS)
C
      REAL RMACH(5)
      SAVE RMACH
C
      EQUIVALENCE (RMACH(1),SMALL(1))
      EQUIVALENCE (RMACH(2),LARGE(1))
      EQUIVALENCE (RMACH(3),RIGHT(1))
      EQUIVALENCE (RMACH(4),DIVER(1))
      EQUIVALENCE (RMACH(5),LOG10(1))
C   ...
      DATA SMALL(1) / 1.18E-38      /
      DATA LARGE(1) / 3.40E+38      /
      DATA RIGHT(1) / 0.595E-07     /
      DATA DIVER(1) / 1.19E-07      /
      DATA LOG10(1) / 0.30102999566 /
C   ...
C***FIRST EXECUTABLE STATEMENT  R1MACH
      IF (I .LT. 1 .OR. I .GT. 5) CALL XERMSG ('SLATEC', 'R1MACH',
     +   'I OUT OF BOUNDS', 1, 2)
C
      R1MACH = RMACH(I)
      RETURN
C
      END
```

Result shows in the following error:

```
    calpuff.for: In function ‘r1mach’:
    calpuff.for:58522: fatal error: gfc_todo: Not Implemented: Initialization of overlapping variables
    compilation terminated.
```

Line 58522 corresponds to the first line of the code shown.

Why does this error occur?

Some information about my compiler: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)

Comment: Please embed code, links die and reduce usefulness of question for future users, and it's not accessible.

Comment: Sorry for my unprofessional. I'll rectify my error.

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it, I'm just a reviewer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known compiler bug in `gfortran`, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31672) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29786). This bug has been fixed in 2007.

Please update to a more recent version of `gfortran`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, you mean by updating my gfortran compiler, The problem could be sovled? I'll try.

Comment: Yes, that should solve it. Version 4.1.2 is **really** old. On my machine (gfortran 5.3) the code compiles fine.

Comment: OK! I'm working on it! One anther question. I have installed WRF(Weather Research Forcast)model in the cluster(I installed gcc 4.2.1 for it). When I update the gcc, are there some incompatible problem?

Comment: Again, this is a new question... One that I cannot answer - I have never been working with that software. But why don't you try and ask a new question once you run into problems?

Comment: Ok! I'll try it by myself first.